# How to change background size/zoom in wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, background, themes

I have a webpage using a wordpress theme:
[image: my web]

The problem is: can you see the white space between the lateral menu and the text? and the white space between the text and the right corner? I want to delete it, like making zoom to the important part of the webpage.

Anyone knows how can I do it? what file and with what vars of the wordpress template I need to play to change this part?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to specify your WordPress theme. Can you?
Do you mean you want to get rid of the side navigation or the styling?
if its the side navigation that you do love to get rid of i suggest you get the secondary menu turn off and for the white spaces i suggest you  might need to have a little custom css to play with.

for the side nav i suggest you try this additional css to get the white spaces off

```
.site-navigation li{border-top:0;}
.secondary-navigation{border-bottom:0}
```

or you can install other css plugins such as simple custom css, css hero,etc
hope that will helps

Comment: Twenty Fourteen.